# Is it possible to access password protected network shared folder without authentication?

Tags: network-shares, shared-folders

Is it possible to access password protected network shared folder (shared by some-other user in the same network)  without providing any of their credentials  ?

Comment: doesn't this defeat the purpose of the password on the share? Or are you asking about getting prompted for a password?

Comment: yes,I do not know the password. I wanted to know If the security can be breached by accessing the data by any other means... like say accessing the data from some different operating system or modifying net bios  (No security is hack proof.)

Comment: You need to talk to your Network/System Admin to get access. The consequences of circumventing a protected share can have legal consequences and/or job loss. Why would we want to be an accessory?

Comment: I had access to a the temp shared folder till day (where I used to keep all my data) and suddenly the folder asks for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

No: No in the sense that you always have to authenticate in order to access these files,

Yes: but if your username and password that you use to login to windows are also set to access this share, windows will not ask for a username and password and you will have access.

Comment: in recent versions of windows (vista and up) you could also use the credential manager in the control panel to store authentication settings once and for all. So the user would not have to provide them on every reboot, but she would *still* have to have credentials to that specific share.

Comment: @amenthes yes, which is the same as checking the box "remember credentials" when logging in. But if your username and password is the same as on the computer that the share is on, and that user is granted permissions, you will not get a login prompt at all, until of course you change your local password.